# How to open DevTools in Opera?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opera, developer-tools

How can I quickly access DevTools in Opera?

When I open `DevTools > Settings > Shortcuts` in Opera and scroll to the bottom of this page, you'll see a link "[Full list of DevTools keyboard shortcuts and gestures](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts)", that points to a document for Google Chrome (a bit weird). Section "[Accessing DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts#accessing-devtools)" says, that to open Developer Tools I should hit <kbd>F12</kbd> key.

Hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> key does nothing in my Opera (`33.0.1990.115`, up to date). What am I missing?

Comment: Not really weird, since Opera uses Blink (since version 15, a.k.a. Chropera) as Chrome does. That section you're referencing happens to be for Chrome, and Opera has its own shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+C, as you can see on the context menu). If you were using Vivaldi (also in the same browser family), you'd see it defaults to Ctrl+Shift+I or F12, but, being Vivaldi, it lets you configure your own preferences.

Comment: a) Because someone else might know another shortcut and have a more complete answer. b) Because it's pretty self-explanatory (just right-click to see the shortcut yourself). c) Because historically, this shortcut has been changing and my answer would only be correct for so long. d) Because I wanted to get my comment about Vivaldi in there - Vivaldi is targetting exactly the kind of users that used to love the old Opera. Enough reasons? ;-)

Comment: Well... :) a) This site is not limited to _one_ answer, b) I have seen _thousands_ of "pretty self-explanatory" answers around SE and by some meaning they also add some value to these sites (people tend to look at answers, not comments!), c) We have an `edit` link around each answer, ya know? :) So... I may agree on (d) comment only, however, you could craft your answer without it and keep that one in a comment. But... after all... it is your answer and no one can force you to write it, if you don't want to (except lord Darth Vader)! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently (up-to-date Opera version is 53.0.2907.57), you can do the following:

- go to the `O` main menu -> `Settings`
- type "short" in the search box on the top to quickly find the
  `Shortcuts` settings
- click `Configure shortcuts` button
- type "dev" in the text box on the top to quickly find the `Developer
  tools` key binding.

This way you can see the current key binding and change the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to more common <kbd>F12</kbd> or whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

go to easy setups --> settings --> and then scroll down to find "shortcuts". Choose "configure shortcuts" --> and then find "Developer Tools Console". If you scroll on the Developer Tools' row, you will see 'Type a shortcut' bar. Click that and press F12. And you can call "Developer Tools" with F12.